# Fabric failed to download settings Error Domain=FABNetworkError Code=-5

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics, google-fabric

I am trying to install Fabric into my iOS app but when I am on the last stage of verifying that everything works, I get this error inside xcode console:

> [Fabric] failed to download settings Error Domain=FABNetworkError
>   Code=-5 "(null)" UserInfo={status_code=403, type=2,
>   request_id=d123378449cf900e4574e283ae438bc5,
>   content_type=application/json; charset=utf-8}

The Fabric application which helps me install Fabric displays the error:

> Hmmm, seems like your kit isn't activating.

This is the code I use to initialise Fabric:

```
[Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]];
```

inside *didFinishLaunchingWithOptions* delegate method.

Some suggested that there is no internet connection when you have this problem, but I am sure that my pc and device are connected to the internet.

I really don't know what to do, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any other crash reporting tool integrated to your project?

Comment: No only Fabric and Crashlytics

Comment: Wrong APIKey can also cause this error.

Comment: In my case it was not set crashlytics in firebase, i needed to press "this app is new to crashlytics" and 403 was gone

Comment: @MyMomSaysIamSpecial Where do you have to press this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found what was wrong. I tried to use the old interface for the crash reports long ago and I have forgotten the script I have placed in Target/Build Phases. When I removed it, everything was fine.

Comment: it doesn't work please give more details. i followed the below steps and getting error on console https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started

Comment: I too am having this problem, I've followed the instructions in the link above.  When I build and run my app in release it installs but never starts running from xcode.  stopping with `[Fabric] failed to download settings Error Domain=FABNetworkError Code=-5 "(null)" UserInfo={status_code=403, type=2, request_id=8d1613386c0b74a2cb3cb6a5de14b8fe, content_type=application/json; charset=utf-8}` as the last line in the console.

Comment: I try delete build phases and add again, after that everything was fine.

Comment: Worked for me as well I too had to delete build phases and add again.

Comment: Worked for me as well, deleting build phases run script and add it again.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this problem when I migrated Fabric Crashlytics to Firebase Crashlytics. If you are migrating you need to make sure that you keep the old initialisation logic i.e. make sure that you still have the old initialisation code:

```
// Objective-C
[FIRApp configure];
[Fabric with:@[CrashlyticsKit]]; // I had removed the this line

// Swift 4
FirebaseApp.configure()
Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
```

You also need to make sure to retain API Key and Build secret in the run script and keep the API Key in your Info.plist.

I had mistakenly removed these things after following the Firebase (non-migration) installation instructions.

[Here's a link to the official installation instructions](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install)

Answer (score 4):

I had my Crashliticy linked to Fabric. That deactivates crashlytics. Under the Firebase project settings I unlinked crashlytics from fabric. Then logout/login again. Then Crashlytics started with the installation process.

Comment: Can you please give more details? I do have the same error. What I did: in project setting in Firebase console ("Integration" tab) I have unlinked Fabric. And now it just shows nothing in Crashlytics tab in the firebase =(.

Comment: This fixed my problem, more info:

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem by adding the API key to the Info.plist .
[image]

```
 <key>Fabric</key>
  <dict>
    <key>APIKey</key>
    <string>your_api_key</string>
    <key>Kits</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>KitInfo</key>
        <dict/>
        <key>KitName</key>
        <string>Crashlytics</string>
      </dict>
    </array>
  </dict>
```

Comment: Worth noting is that the fabric config needs to be at the top of the .plist. I tried placing it as the last entry which I now bitterly regret.

Answer (score 2):

If you have this issue when using Firebase it's because Crashlytics won't be activated until you follow the configuration process in Firebase console :

1. in Firebase console, click on Crashlytics link on the left panel
2. follow the steps until it ask you to run the application

Comment: This - I wasted tons of time not following the pathway set out in the firebase console. This resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

With XCode 10 under the RunScript section you have to add the following line to Input Files:

$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)

Comment: I also added this for Xcode 11; not sure if its required for v11 or not; but I managed to get things working simply by following @George 's instructions above

Comment: This worked for Xcode 11.2.1 (11B53), Crashlytics (3.14.0), Fabric (1.10.2). You just have to wait for like 2 3 mins once you make call to the server.

Comment: This answer is documented by Google here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios#initialize

Answer (score 1):

I know, that it is something strange, but for me solution was **to run on simulator**.

All suggest above not worked for me.

1) Start initializing app in Console -> Crashlytics

2) Do all necessary things (run script phase etc)

3) Run on simulator

After installation is completed, I can see all my test crashes in console from device.

Answer (score 1):

@Marc Fdn solution fixed my problem:

1. Open https://console.firebase.google.com/
2. Project overview > Project Settings

   [image: Project overview > Project Settings]
3. In the `Integrations` Tab, click `Manage` and delete the Fabric integration

   [image]
4. Go back to the Firebase/Crashlitics page and re-add your app, the webpage may show several loading errors, probably Firebase needs a bit of time for update the data, don't worry, wait a bit and continue to refresh.

Comment: Thanks for the best solution in the world

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any ad blocking software setup on your network? cause that's what caused this error for me.